# Is $\tan x\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}\implies x\notin\mathbb{Q}$ always true?

Tags: trigonometry, irrational-numbers, pi

While proving that $\pi$ is irrational, Johann Heinrich Lambert proved that
$$x\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}\implies \tan x\notin\mathbb{Q},$$
but is it always true that
$$\tan x\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}\implies x\notin\mathbb{Q}?$$
If not, what is $x$ such that the statement is not true?

Comment: How far did you get by taking the contrapositive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contrapositive of the statement is that if $\tan x\in\mathbb Q$, then $x\notin\mathbb Q-\{0\}$. Thus if $\tan x\in \mathbb Q-\{0\}$, then it's still true that $x\notin \mathbb Q-\{0\}$, but additionally $x\neq 0$ because $\tan x\neq 0$, so $x\notin\mathbb Q$.